# Can I drop the home directory from an user in Linux/Centos

Tags: linux, centos, samba

I've installed Samba in my CentOS server. also I've created users (`useradd -s /sbin/nologin example_user. smbpasswd -a user`) to manage the files in some directoriess.  For example,  `/home/purchases_files` for two users.

My question is that when I created the users in my home directory the system created directories with the name of the user, but I don't want to save those directories.

Will I have troubles in the future if i drop those directories?   or do i need to save them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the samba config you can specify where you want the mount points to be - there is no obligation to support user home directories if they are not needed.  There is usually a rule in the samba config file you simply need to remove - and then you are free to drop the users home directories.

Example smb.conf

```
[global]
  workgroup = METRAN
  encrypt passwords = yes
  wins support = yes
  log level = 1 
  max log size = 1000
  read only = no
[homes] 
  browsable = no
  map archive = yes
[test]
  browsable = yes
  read only = yes
  path = /usr/local/samba/tmp
```

e.g. remove [homes] section

Comment: I'll drop them :3 thanks